# how to use async series inside a for loop in coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, async.js

I am using caolan's async lib in coffeescript. My tasks are inside a for loop and after the loop is fully executed I need to run the callback function.

This is what I have now. I do not want the final callback to run everytime inside the for loop. How can I do this?

```
 for key, value of settings
  async.series([
    ((callback) ->
      getSetting key, (value) ->
        #do something and create object settingValues
      callback(null, settingValues)
    )
  ],
  #final callback which I want to run after the entire for loop is completed.  
  (err, results) ->
    someFunction results
  )
```

Comment: Use `async.series` ***instead*** of the `for` loop???

Comment: How? I need to iterate through the settings object

Comment: Oh, right, it's not `.series`, but rather `.mapSeries` or `.eachSeries` or [some other collection iteration method](https://github.com/caolan/async#collections). I was confused because you were using `series` for a single task which makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks. That helped.

Comment: @muistooshort: Really? I don't want to reopen it as it's already solved and probably a dupe of "async.js howto", but I can't see how the linked question has anything to with this

Comment: @Bergi: The obvious issue (to me) is that the `key` in `getSettings key...` will always be the last value from `for key, ...` (i.e. the standard "closure inside a loop" problem) but maybe I'm only seeing the next bug. I'll re-open it, I think I misinterpreted what's going on.

Comment: @muistooshort: Ah, right, that's another problem. But if you're using an `async` function to iterate instead of the loop, the issue will go away by itself :-)

Comment: @Bergi: Yeah,  proper iterator use should sort it all out, I don't know my way around async.js enough to say much though. Thanks for pointing out my brain damage :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use `async.series` the for-loop to construct an array of functions, then pass the array

```
 arr = []

 for key, value of settings
   arr.push (callback) ->
     getSetting key, (value) -> 
       callback(null, settingValues)


 async.series arr, (err, results) -> someFunction results
```

Alternately, you can just use async to iterate

```
async.map Object.keys(settings), (key, callback) ->
    # if you need 'value' in here, use settings[key]
    getSetting key, (value) ->
      callback(null, settingValues)
, (err, results) -> someFunction results
```